# assign names of elements in a list in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, assign

I have a list of dataframes like this:

```
listofdfs <- list(x <- data.frame("a"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(35,30,20)), y <- data.frame("a"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(6,21,40)) )
```

and a vector of labels:

```
label <- c("hi","hello")
```

Now I have:

```
[[1]]
     a  b
1 2009 35
2 2010 30
3 2011 20

[[2]]
     a  b
1 2009  6
2 2010 21
3 2011 40
```

and using a for loop I'd like to obtain:

```
$hi
     a  b
1 2009 35
2 2010 30
3 2011 20

$hello
     a  b
1 2009  6
2 2010 21
3 2011 40
```

I tried whit this code but there's something I miss:

```
for (i in label) {
   for (j in 1:length(listofdfs)){
      names(listofdfs)[j] <- i
  }
}
```

because I get:

```
$hello
     a  b
1 2009 35
2 2010 30
3 2011 20

$hello
     a  b
1 2009  6
2 2010 21
3 2011 40
```

What should I add or edit to my code?
Thank you!

Comment: You can simply do `setNames(listofdfs, label)`.

Comment: Or `names(listofdfs) <- label`